# Convergence of heat flow, lemma 3.5.4 in Jost's book

Tags: riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions, heat-equation

I am trying to understand Lemma 3.5.4 in Jost's book *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis, 7-ed* and running into some troubles.

[image]

[image]
[image]

It seems that the notation is not consistent. In the Lemma, I think $H\beta_0$ is the harmonic p-form of the limit of the heat flow with initial condition $\beta(x,0) = \beta_0(x)$. Then, my question comes from the first sentence of the proof.

> Given $t>0$, we seek $\beta$ with $\left\Vert \beta \right\Vert = 1$ and $H\beta = 0$ for which for the solution $\beta$ of (3.5.1) $$ \frac{\partial\beta(x,t)}{\partial t} + \Delta \beta(x,t) = 0 $$ with the initial value $\beta(x,0)=\beta(x)$, $\left\Vert \beta(.,t) \right\Vert$ is maximal.

1. What is the $\beta$ we seek in the beginning? $\beta$ is a solution of heat equation or an initial condition?
2. For a given $t>0$, if we can find such $\beta$, then $\beta$ depends on $t$? To avoid abuse of notation, if we call $t'$ for the given time parameter, we should write $\beta^{(t')}(x)$ or $\beta^{(t')}(x,t)$.
3. *Maxmial* is in what sense? Among all choice of $\beta$?

Comment: Right, they use $\beta$ to denote everything and this is confusing. The running variable is $\beta(\cdot, 0)$, which is a generic $p$-form with $\lVert \beta(\cdot, 0)\rVert =1$, and must be chosen in such a way that $\lVert \beta(\cdot, t)\rVert$ is maximum. Recall that $t$ has been fixed in the beginning. This is how I interpret that.

Comment: The problem has to be understood this way: consider the set of $\beta$($= x\mapsto \beta(x)$) such that $H\beta = 0$ and $\|\beta\| = 1$. On this set, consider the function $\beta \mapsto \|\beta(\cdot,t)\|$ ($t$ is fixed), which is well defined. The aim is to maximize this function.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Let $S = \{ \beta: x \mapsto \beta(x) | H\beta = 0, \left\Vert \beta \right\Vert = 1 \}$, and let $\overline{\beta}$ be the heat solution with the initial condition $\beta$. Then $b(t) = \text{max} \left\Vert \overline{\beta}(.,t) \right\Vert$ where maximum is taken over $\beta \in S$. Is that correct? If so, then by using the semigroup property, I can show $b(2t) \le b(t)^2$.

Comment: Now my only question remaining is why the maximum is well-defined? It says the $C^{1,\alpha}$-norm of $\overline{\beta}(.,t)$ is bounded in terms of $\left\Vert \beta \right\Vert $, which is $1$, so the maximum is attained. But I can't see why (I am not familiar with Holder space).

Comment: @JustinLien Yes you are right. Choosing a maximizing sequence $(\beta_n)$ + compactness properties (if $M$ is compact) and completeness of $\mathcal{C}^{1,\alpha}$ should solve your problem

Comment: @Didier Could you provide more detail please? I couldn't figure out what you mean. So $S = \{ \beta \in C^{2,\alpha} | H\beta = 0, \left\Vert \beta \right\Vert_{L^2(M)} = 1 \} \subset C^{2,\alpha}$ and I want to show that the maximum $\left\Vert \overline{\beta}(.,t) \right\Vert_{L^2(M)}$ over $S$ is achieved. Which space is compact (in which norm)? Why do we use $C^{1,\alpha}$ norm instead of $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm? Btw, I appreciate it if you have any relevant materials so that I can have a better understanding.